# How to switch \n to a newline in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    with open("C:\\test\\data1.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    tail = data[-10:]
```

I have a file name data1.txt inside folder test, when my program reads from the file it reads the whole content from the file and prints only the last 10 lines from the file.

> ['this is line number 21\n', 'this is line number 22\n', 'this is line
>   number 23\n', 'this is line number 24\n', 'this is line number 25\n',
>   'this is line number 26\n', 'this is line number 27\n', 'this is line
>   number 28\n', 'this is line number 29\n', 'this is line number 30\n']

I want to print the last 10 lines from the file with line breaks but cant figure how I can put inside a line break inside a list data structure.

for example : 
To print txt file (data1.txt) like that :

this is line number 21

this is line number 22

this is line number 23

this is line number 24

without the \n and the list deceleration ([' '])

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you add a concrete example of what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm expecting to get each line individually exanple : this is line number 21 and new line and this is line number 22 and so on ... to make the /n make an effect and not be an ordaniry string

Comment: Add an example **to your question** not to a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many answers already, but no one explained the problem.

### Problem

`\n` **is** the newline character!

### Explanation

In order to be able show the newline within a string literal, the escape sequence `\n` is used, e.g.:

```
>>> 'a\nb'
'a\nb'

>>> print('a\nb')
a
b
```

`print` function prints the string, if a string argument is passed to it, but if some other object is passed to it, it first has to be converted to a string, so `print(x)` is the same as `print(str(x))`.

When a `list` of strings is converted to string, that is done by calling [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) on each of its items:

```
>>> ['a', 'a\nb']
['a', 'a\nb']

>>> str(['a', 'a\nb'])
"['a', 'a\\nb']"

>>> print("['a', 'a\\nb']")
['a', 'a\nb']
```

### Solution

Now, if you want to print the last 10 lines, it means you should print each string in the list, not the list object itself, e.g.:

```
for s in list_of_strings:
    print(s)
```

Now, since the `s` already contains a newline and `print` adds a newline itself, you should remove one of the newlines to make the solution complete:

```
for s in list_of_strings:
    print(s.strip('\n'))
```

or:

```
for s in list_of_strings:
    print(s, end='')
```

or create one string by concatenating items of the list and print that:

```
print(''.join(list_of_strings))
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation .. Great !

Answer (score 1):

Just `print` tail like this:

```
print(*tail, sep='')
```

The `sep` argument stops the automatic space that is normally used as a separator between printed items.

Comment: Amm.., should say that does not work on python 2...

Comment: @U9-Forward You _can_  use the `print` function in Python 2.6+, you just need from `__future__ import print_function` at the top of the script (the __future__ module should not be imported after other imports).

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: @PM2Ring Correct, My bad, my mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best is a join (works on any version):

```
print(''.join(tail))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
f.readlines()[-10:]
```

this way you will get last 10 lines.

Or just:

```
data = f.readlines()[-10:]
for d in data:
   print(d) # will print everything on new line
```

Comment: Amm..., `[-10:]`...